# How to find the maximum value in join without using if in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a two tables like below

```
A
Id Name
1   a
2   b

B
Id Name
1  t
6  s
```

My requirement is to find the maximum id from  table and display the name and id for that maximum without using case and if.

i findout the maximum by using below query

```
SELECT MAX(id)
  FROM (SELECT id,name  FROM A
        UNION
        SELECT id,name FROM B) as c
```

I findout the maximum 6 using the above query.but i can't able to find the name.I tried the below query but it's not working

```
SELECT MAX(id)
  FROM (SELECT id,name  FROM A
        UNION
        SELECT id,name FROM B) as c
```

How to find the name?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: MYSQL or SQL-Server? Can't be both :)

Comment: If SQL Server you can use any of the rank functions answers mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First combine the tables, since you need to search both. Next, determine the `id` you need. `JOIN` the `id` back with the temporarily created table to retreive the `name` that belongs to that `id`:

```
WITH tmpTable AS (
    SELECT id,name  FROM A
    UNION
    SELECT id,name FROM B
)

, max AS (
    SELECT MAX(id) id 
    FROM tmpTable
)

SELECT t.id, t.name
FROM max m
JOIN tmpTable t ON m.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER()`. You have to `UNION ALL` `TableA` and `TableB` first.

```
WITH TableA(Id, Name) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'b'
)
,TableB(Id, Name) AS(
    SELECT 1, 't' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 's'
)
,Combined(Id, Name) AS(
    SELECT * FROM TableA UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM TableB
)
,CTE AS(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) FROM Combined
)
SELECT Id, Name
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just order by over the union and take first row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT * FROM A UNION SELECT * FROM B) x
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

This won't show ties though.

Answer (score 0):

For you stated that you used **SQL Server 2008**. Therefore,I used `FULL JOIN` and `NESTED SELECT` to get what your looking for. See below:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT 
     1,
     ISNULL(A.Id,B.Id)Id
FROM A FULL JOIN B ON A.Id=B.Id) AS Id,
(SELECT
     1,
     ISNULL(A.Name,B.Name)Name
FROM A FULL JOIN B ON A.Id=B.Id) AS Name
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `ROW_NUMBER()` or `DENSE_RANK()` functions to get new numiration by Id, and then select value with newly created `orderId` equal to 1

Use:

- `ROW_NUMBER()` to get only one value (even if there are some repetitions of max id)
- `DENSE_RANK()` to get all equal max id values

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @tb1 AS TABLE
(
    Id INT
    ,[Name] NVARCHAR(255)
)

DECLARE @tb2 AS TABLE
(
    Id INT
    ,[Name] NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO  @tb1 VALUES (1, 'A');
INSERT INTO  @tb1 VALUES (7, 'B');
INSERT INTO  @tb2 VALUES (4, 'C');
INSERT INTO  @tb1 VALUES (7, 'D');

SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT Id, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) AS [orderId]
    FROM 
        (SELECT Id, Name  FROM @tb1
        UNION
        SELECT Id, Name FROM @tb2) as tb3) AS TB
WHERE [orderId] = 1

SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT Id, Name, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) AS [orderId]
    FROM 
        (SELECT Id, Name  FROM @tb1
        UNION
        SELECT Id, Name FROM @tb2) as tb3) AS TB
WHERE [orderId] = 1
```

Results are:

[image]